# How to modify specific line in sql file?

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to modify a line in sql file in a directory. 
Currently have written the code which navigates to files directory according to user input .

each sql file in that dir has these 2 lines:

```
--liquibase formatted sql
--changeset Jack:1 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false
```

I am trying to do is loop through all files and I want to change-set every-time the script runs.

so those 2 lines will look like this :

```
 --liquibase formatted sql
 --changeset Ryan:2 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false
```

The part I want to change in line is constant but the content is different for each file like in other file it will be `Jie:6` I want to replace that with `Priyal:7`. So the name part is the person who is running the script and the number after : is incremented

Is there a cleaner way to  achieve this :

This is just sample code I have which configures path and everything :

```
anbpath = os.path.abspath("copy_views.py")
 print(anbpath)

sqldir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ), '..', 'database')) 

path_to_views = sqldir+"/sql/edm/changes/"+source_release_version+"/mutable/view"
print(path_to_views)


destdir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ),'..', 'database')) 

path_to_dest_rel_ver = destdir+"/sql/edm/changes/"+dest_release_version

path_to_dest = path_to_dest_rel_ver+"/mutable/view"
```

I will traverse all files in `path_to_dest` using `os.walk`

Comment: Please correct the formats, code indentation and typos in your question.

Comment: Hope looks good now @gdlmx

Comment: Updated the format properly

Comment: @PriyalChaudhari you want `name4:6` to be replace to `name5:7` i.e leave the name as it is and increment both the numbers ?

Comment: @mujjiga Actual content is Jack:1 or Ryan:4 like that those are demo names I have used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your file is called "file.txt" and if the `name` is constant then what you are looking for is

```
# Read the contents of file
with open("file.txt", 'r') as fp:
    lines = fp.readlines()

#Idendify tokens and numbers with in them and increment them
words = lines[1].split()
tokens = words[1].split(":")
words[1] = "name{0}:{1}".format(int(tokens[0][4:])+1, int(tokens[1])+1)
lines[1] = ' '.join(words)

# Write back the updated lines
with open("file.txt", 'w') as fp:
    fp.writelines(lines)
```

Initial content of file

`"--liquibase formatted sql",
 "--changeset name3:21 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false"]`

Afer modification

`"--liquibase formatted sql",
 "--changeset name4:22 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false"]`

However, if the `name` is not constant then we can still split the token at ":" to indentify the number after ":" but to indentify the number ending at the name we will have to use regex.

Comment: Thanks this helps . No there is no number after name. Those are just demo names I used. Actual names are like Jack, Ryan so . I will have to worry about number after :

Comment: My file has .sql extension

Comment: I think this solution will create problems as file has sql code as well these 2 lines are at start of file. If I split on : that will split the sql code as well. I do not want to touch that part

Comment: @PriyalChaudhari If you look at the code I am only working on the second line `lines[1]` The code does not touch/modify the other lines. So as long as it is in the 2nd line it should work.

Comment: got it i will try this thanks. Just not sure about the part how to handle real actual names.

Comment: I think `with` does not support `.sql` file it does not open

Comment: Is it not a text file with just a .sql extension or is it a binary file ? What is the error

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex to solve this:
The following code will replace the string "name1:1" by "name2:2" if it finds the correct sequence and preserve the rest of the line:

```py
import re

# read the file, line by line and then:
line_fixed = re.sub(r"(--changeset )name1:1(.*)", r"\1name2:2\2", line)
# then save the fixed line to a temporary file until you read all file
```

Comment: ABOVE I USED A EXAMPLE. Its not alwats` name1:1` its different in every file like in some file it might be `name8:6`

Comment: I hope you can use my answer as an "example" and guideline to solve your problem. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with regular expressions:

```
import re

lines = [
    "--liquibase formatted sql",
    "--changeset Jack:2 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false",
    "--liquibase formatted sql",
    "--changeset Ryan:6 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false",
#   etc ...
]

def update_line(line):
    p = re.compile(r'--changeset (.+):(\d+) runOnChange')
    matches = p.match(line)
    if not matches:
        return line
    else:
        replacement = '--changeset {}:{} runOnChange'.format(matches.group(1),
                                                             int(matches.group(2))+1)
        return p.sub(replacement, line)

for line in lines:
    updated_line = update_line(line)
    print(repr(updated_line))
```

Output:

```
'--liquibase formatted sql'
'--changeset Jack:3 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false'
'--liquibase formatted sql'
'--changeset Ryan:7 runOnChange:true splitStatements:false stripComments:false'
```